# Understanding ":not" syntax in Angular RouterLink selector specification

Tags: angular, css-selectors

The Angular documentation at https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink describes the use of the `routerLink` attribute that is typically used on anchor tags:

`<a routerLink="/Heroes">Go to Heroes</a>`

The documentation specifies the applicable selector as

`:not(a):not(area)[routerLink]`

I read this as "any element *besides* `a` and `area` having a `routerLink` attribute", which seems to be the opposite of what's intended. I would have expected

`a[routerLink], area[routerLink]`

Can anyone set me straight on this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `:not(a):not(area)[routerLink]` means the following: any element with a tag name other than `a` and `area` but with the `routerLink` attribute

Comment: Right, hence my bafflement, since `a` tags are basically what the `routerLink` attribute is *for*.

Comment: from https://medium.com/swlh/anatomy-of-angular-attribute-directive-selector-a1d83a73242 "Exclusion selectors can be chained together to further refine the query...so is applied to any element but has not **together** a and area